# How to configure emacs to start in the middle of the screen, and not in the top left corner?

Tags: frames, start-up, config

Currently have a GUI version of GNU Emacs v.26.3 (on MacOS Catalina, also have a similar version on Ubuntu 16.04), and because I'm just getting started with the editor, I have this question: how do I configure it to start up in the middle of the screen, and not in top-left corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize `default-frame-list` to have values for frame parameters `top` and `left` that put it in the middle of your screen. (Use `M-x customize-option default-frame-alist`.)

If that doesn't do the job then try the same thing with `initial-frame-alist` instead (or in addition).

Comment: thank you, I'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

I tried both methods and still not centring on the screen.

Comment: I tried posting as a question to but was unable as said to fix the error I tried changing the tag name but was unsuccessful. I want to ask the same question as the answer given did not work.

Comment: Check out the `frame-center` function I wrote as an answer to this question.

Comment: Thank-you G Gundam, That's what I needed and works.  Shame it was so difficult to find an answer and not much on the web about it. Many thanks James

Comment: Hi again, The centring works when called with M-x frame-center but not on emacs loading, I have to call it. I put your code in my emacs config and tried adding (frame-center t) but that did not work. Any thoughts, much appreciated. James

Comment: I checked through my config and other settings for the size and placing of default window, I took them out and now my window open just off center, then when I run frame-center it corrects to the center. This is good enough for me, for now , many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that can be called to center the current frame.

```lisp
(defun frame-center ()
  "Center the current frame."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((dw (display-pixel-width))
         (dh (display-pixel-height))
         (f  (selected-frame))
         (fw (frame-pixel-width f))
         (fh (frame-pixel-height f))
         (x  (- (/ dw 2) (/ fw 2)))
         (y  (- (/ dh 2) (/ fh 2))))
    (message (format "dw %d dh %d fw %d fh %d x %d y %d" dw dh fw fh x y))
    (set-frame-position f x y)))
```

It can be called interactively via <kbd>M-x frame-center</kbd> or it can be placed in your config file to center your emacs on startup.

```lisp
(frame-center)
```